# How to restructure my data frame in python to meet a certain view - T & melt functions didn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, pivot-table

I have the following data that I want to change structure from
[it current format here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cCpE.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SESSION ID': [123456,789456,101112,131415],
                  'APP-F': [3,2,4,3],'APP-M':[3,3,3,3],
                  'COM-F':[3,3,3,3],'COM-M':[3,3,3,3],
                  'RTW-F':[3,2,3,3],'RTW-F':[3,3,3,3]  })


| SESSION ID| APP-F | APP-M | COM-F | COM-M | RTW-F | RTW-M |
| ---       | ---   | ---   | ---   | ---   | ---   | ---   |
| 123456    | 3     | 3     | 3     | 3     | 3     | 3     |
| 789456    | 2     | 3     | 3     | 3     | 2     | 3     |
| 101112    | 4     | 3     | 3     | 3     | 2     | 3     |
| 131415    | 4     | 3     | 3     | 3     | 2     | 3     |
```

In the data sample you see above, I measure certain competencies such as APP, COM, and RTW to compare males (M) and females (F) across different training sessions. I tried both melt and transpose functions to help me  [achieve this final format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tYaD.png) with no luck.

```
df_transpose=df.T
df_transpose.head()
```

[data after I used the above transpose command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQoC8.png)

the closest I got was when I split the data to F and M the I use **iterrows**

```
_list = []

for row_index,row in df.iterrows():
    r = row.to_dict()
    _list.append(r)

_list
```

The output looks very similar to what I want but how can I export it to file?

[Here is how the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI12d.png)

Comment: kindly post the data as text, not pics; also, kindly add your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is with pandas' wide_to_long, you do need to reshape the columns:

```py
temp = df.set_index('SESSION ID')
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('-').str[::-1].str.join('-')
pd.wide_to_long(
    temp.reset_index(), 
    stubnames=['F','M'], 
    sep='-', 
    i='SESSION ID', 
    j='other', 
    suffix='.+').dropna()

                  F    M
SESSION ID other
123456     APP    3  3.0
789456     APP    2  3.0
101112     APP    4  3.0
131415     APP    3  3.0
123456     COM    3  3.0
789456     COM    3  3.0
101112     COM    3  3.0
131415     COM    3  3.0
```

Comment: ``` 
| SESSION ID| other | F | M|
123456            | APP     | 3  |  3 | 
123456            |COM     | 3  |  3 |
123456            |RTW     | 3  |  3 |
``` 
@sammywemmy is there a way to make the output look like the above sample?

Comment: @Mona not that I'm aware of